# When is it acceptable to use Gauss' Law for a line charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

I'm having trouble determining when it's acceptable to use Gauss' Law and when I have to integrate Coulombs law. If I am given a line charge and asked to find the electric field at a point r from the line, is it correct to say that I can only enclose the line in a cylinder and find the field using Gauss' law if the line is infinite? What if the point is directly above the center of the line? Do I have to integrate Coulombs Law taking into account the direction of each field and how they cancel/add or is there a way to use Gauss' Law here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gauss' law always holds however it is only useful by itself when there is some kind of symmetry that you can exploit. Otherwise you only know the flux through a surface but not the electric field.

In the case of an infinite line charge, the symmetry means that the electric field is radial at all points on a cylinder around the line charge.

For a finite length line charge this is not the case since the field is not radial about the line charge (it bends and wraps around at the ends).

Therefore you can only solve the infinite case with Gauss' law, you will have to do the integration for the other case. Note that Gauss' law is derived directly from Coulomb's law, so whenever you can use Gauss' law, you can always integrate too, it just may be more work.

---

I don't know what you mean by "the point is directly above the center of the line". If the point is on the line then clearly the electric field is $0$, and if it is a distance $r$ from it then you can calculate it as described above.

Comment: Thanks, by directly above the center of the line I meant on it's perpendicular bisector.

Comment: @L.Rothman Yes, that is fine - either use Gauss for infinite, or integration for finite.